# Filter duplicate values in select2 ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-select2

I'm using select2 load remote data way to render results (50 at a time) from an api. The response of the api might have duplicate values in any page response.

I have tried formatting response but unfortunately the method is having access only to the current page data.

Below is my code,

```
jQuery('#items').select2({
    minimumInputLength : 2,
    placeholder        : '-- Select Items --',
    ajax : {
        url      : '/api/v1/items',
        quietMillis : 200,
        dataType : 'json', 
        data     : function (term, page) {
            return {
                term : term,
                page : page,
                page_limit : 50
            };
        },
        results  : function(data, page) {
            //Here I'm getting only current page data. How can i get previous page data to check for duplicate values.
        } 
    }
});
```

So, how can I filter the response and eliminate duplicate values by checking against the data fetched so far.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: show your code for better clarification.

Comment: I have updated my code. I hope it would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

It would be better if you post an example of your code. Let's say you have some data with duplicated entries:

```js
var rawData = [
  {
    id: 'AL',
    name: 'Alaska'
  },
  {
    id: 'GE',
    name: 'Georgia'
  },
  {
    id: 'WY',
    name: 'Wyoming'
  },
  {
    id: 'GE',
    name: 'Georgia'
  }
];


function clearDuplicates(data) {
  var temp = {};
  
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    temp[data[i]['id']] = data[i];
  }
  
  return Object.values(temp);
}


var clearData = clearDuplicates(rawData);

console.log(clearData);
```

See output: duplicated entry 'Georgia' is now in one record. There can be a lot of ways to eliminate duplicates. This is just one simple example.

---

**UPDATE:**

If you use pagination (infinite scroll) in Select2, every page request is sent separately and you have to process result data and eliminate duplicates manually. it can be done by `processResults` parameter. (See [example](https://select2.org/data-sources/ajax#additional-examples))

In that case, easiest way would be:

1. Handle every page request in `processResults`
2. Store all results in a global variable
3. Eliminate duplicates as described in the example above
4. Return desired result

Return:

```
  return {
    results: <YOUR_FILTERED_DATA>,
    pagination: {
      //paginatioin params
    }
  }
```

Comment: I really appreciate your response. I have updated the code. But i do not have static data, since the data is fetched by the ajax call

Comment: You can process duplicates in `results: function(data, page) {  }` and select will take  return of this function.

Comment: Currently I'm using results callback but unfortunately it does not have all the data. It is having only the current page (50) data

Comment: It seems you have a different question, then you asked. Idk how select2 works, but you need to retrieve previous page data in callback somehow. Maybe another ajax call or save it before page change.